# How to organize folders when I make a multiple page website?

Tags: html, file, web, assets

I'm building a multiple page website, and i would like to know what is the best way to organize folders for each page?

## 1

This is what i did:
I created a main folder named: **www.mywebsite.com**

## 2

And in that folder i created a **folder for each page**:

[image: I created a folder for each page]

## 3

in the assets folder i have js, css, img

[image]

Is this the correct way of doing it or is there any better way, i know i can import, in my sass file other sass files and create a main file, but im not sure is that a good way?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a folder for every page. Just put your html in root folder and make a directory for js, images and css.

Comment: But then my url will look like for example: www.mywebsite.com/about.html and i dont want that i want it to be  like: www.mywebsite.com/about

Comment: The way you're stucturing this is going to look like www.mywebsite.com/about/about.html. You need to play with the htaccess file in order to not display the extentions.

Comment: Check out +MultiViews.

Answer (score 0):

Your pages don't need sub folders, they're just for assets that are going to be called in i.e.e an images folder for your images and an assets folder for your CSS or JS files. If you add your pages to a sub folder then you'd need to add that into the URL: string i.e. mywebsite/home/home.html. Also, your server is looking in the root folder for home.html, or index.html (dependent on server), so it won't know where to point when you just type in mywebsite.com

Don;t forget to account for the folder paths when calling any of these in your HTML files i.e. your menu can just call '/home.html', '/about.html' etc While anything in a sub folder will need to be referenced as such i.e. 'images/image.png'

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for that much folders - you can put all files in the root folder or in separate folders (that lie in the root folder) for html, css, js, php and so on